# How do I extract digits from a string with spaces and dashes in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a phone number, i.e., just the digits from a string that may have dashes, parentheses, spaces, etc.

The problem is that `print(f"number: {match}")` returns an empty list.

My code:

```py
import re

number_pattern = re.compile(r'\d{10}')
match = number_pattern.findall('(289)925-4 931')
print(f"number: {match}")
if match: 
    match = ''.join(match)
    if len(match) > 9:
        print("digits: " + match)
```

Comment: Remove the `{10}` from your regexp, that looks for 10 digits in a row

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your regex is looking for 10 consecutive digits (`{10}`). Remove that and it'll work.

But no regex is actually needed:

```
print(''.join(c for c in '(289)925-4 931' if c.isdigit()))
# '2899254931'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
import re

number_pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
match = number_pattern.findall('(289)925-4 931')
print(f"number: {match}")
if match: 
    match = ''.join(match)
    if len(match) > 9:
        print("digits: " + match)
```

I've changed the regex to d+ instead of d{10}

the output will be

```
number: ['289', '925', '4', '931']
digits: 2899254931
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@BoppreH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78172733/18470692), your code will work fine with `re.compile(r'\d')`. Alternatively, you could also use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and replace all non-digits (`\D`) with an empty string:

```py
import re
          
digits = re.sub(r'\D', '', '(289)925-4 931')
print(f'digits: {digits}')

digits: 2899254931
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then capture what you DO want, you can split by what you DON'T want:

```
>>> import re
>>> ''.join(re.split(r'\D', '(289)925-4 931'))
'2899254931'
```

If you are looking for a test that you are only matching a total of 10 digits otherwise the whole match is not valid, I would do something like this:

```
>>> tgt='(289)925-4 931'
>>> phone=fd if len(fd:=''.join(re.findall(r'\d', tgt)))==10 else ''
>>> phone
'2899254931'
>>> tgt='(289)925-4 93'
>>> phone=fd if len(fd:=''.join(re.findall(r'\d', tgt)))==10 else ''
>>> phone
''
```